# Regex replace text outside html tags

Tags: html, regex, replace

I have this HTML:

```
"This is simple html text <span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span> text"
```

I need to match only words that are outside any HTML tag. I mean if I want to match “simple” and “text” I should get the results only from “This is simple html text” and the last part “text”—the result will be “simple” 1 match, “text” 2 matches. Could anyone help me with this? I’m using jQuery.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b" + value + "\\b)", 'gi');

if (pattern.test(text)) {
    text = text.replace(pattern, "<span class='notranslate'>$1</span>");
}
```

- `value` is the word I want to match (in this case “simple”)
- `text` is `"This is simple html text <span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span> text"`

I need to wrap all selected words (in this example it is “simple”) with `<span>`. But I want to wrap only words that are outside *any* HTML tags. The result of this example should be

```
This is <span class='notranslate'>simple</span> html <span class='notranslate'>text</span> <span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span> <span class='notranslate'>text</span>
```

I do not want replace any text inside

```
<span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span>
```

It should be the same as before replacement.

Comment: Could you mention the language you're using and the desired result of the replacement in your question please?

Comment: @Jerry, The example was added.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Okay, try using this regex:

```
(text|simple)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</)
```

[Example worked on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/1).

Breakdown:

```
(         # Open capture group
  text    # Match 'text'
|         # Or
  simple  # Match 'simple'
)         # End capture group
(?!       # Negative lookahead start (will cause match to fail if contents match)
  [^<]*   # Any number of non-'<' characters
  >       # A > character
|         # Or
  [^<>]*  # Any number of non-'<' and non-'>' characters
  </      # The characters < and /
)         # End negative lookahead.
```

The negative lookahead will prevent a match if `text` or `simple` is between html tags.

Comment: Yeees! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! You are my hero! :)

Comment: @Sanya530 :( Maybe try escaping the forward slash `(text|simple)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)`? I don't know on what engine IE rolls on, but if it's similar to Javascript, that should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry! It was my mistake in JS. Everything is working PERFECT in IE8. Thank you!

Comment: It took me two days to figure this out. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly

Comment: Tried so many approaches before being pointed here. Perfect solution for my needs. Thanks for the detailed breakdown too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: Wow! What a nice and smooth solution.

Comment: adjusted for javascript (wordtomatch)(?![^<]*>)/gm

Comment: @JoakimPoromaaHelger note that your 'adjusted' version isn't quite like how the OP wanted, since yours also replaces texts between `<span> ... </span>`, which is not desired here.

Comment: @JoakimPoromaaHelger No issues, it's a learning process ^^

Comment: Nice example, what if I want to match all words inside html tags?

Comment: @Muhammad Possibly use something like this `(text|simple)(?=[^<>]*>)`

Comment: thank you @Jerry, actually I want to wrap all words inside a html documents with spans but in some cases its breaking the html, this is how I am currently doing it `content.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, "$1<text class="word">$2</text>")`

Comment: How to use it for a specific `<a>` tag?

Comment: @A.Seddighi You would have to use a pattern for that specific `<a>` tag in the negative lookahead

Comment: @Jerry Please reply in personal chat room when you get a chance

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^<]*)<\w+.*/\w+>([^<]*)$
```

However this is a very naive expression.  It would be better to use a DOM parser.

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to get all 'simple' matches outside the tags how this example will look like? The reason I asking is I need to get the Regex pattern and then replace all matches of 'simple' word outside the tags.