# How can I use Javascript to wrap a matched string without killing existing events?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Using vanilla Javascript I am trying to replace some text, anywhere it shows up on the page, with an anchor, unless it is already in an anchor. But I don't want to kill existing events. So, for example, this:

```
<body>
<p>The text I want to replace is awesomeness. Whatever has awesomeness should be replaced. Unless it is <a href="#" class="existingLink">an awesomeness link</a>.</p>
</body>
```

...should become this:

```
<body>
<p>The text I want to replace is <a href="/coolness/">awesomeness</a>. Whatever has <a href="/coolness/">awesomeness</a> should be replaced. Unless it is <a href="#" class="existingLink">an awesomeness link</a>.</p>
</body>
```

However, any onclick or onmouseover or onanything events that have already been assigned to (for example) the existingLink should remain. I tried replacing the innerHTML of the `<p>` tag, but that kills the events assigned to existingLink. I can't seem to figure out any other way to make the switch though. Something along these lines is done by [reftagger](http://reftagger.com/). I am trying to do something similar to what reftagger does (only on a much smaller level). A super simple example would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to manipulate text nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an `Element`'s `innerHTML` will replace all of its `childNodes` and any event listeners attached to them. Therefore, you'll need to iterate over the `childNodes`, and replace any text nodes which contain the search term with a series of subnodes separated by anchor `Elements`.

This is a bit tricky, so you might want to look for a library. However, the following code is vanilla JavaScript and it solves your problem. (The **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/579Lp/1/)**, tested in Chrome and Firefox, shows that event listeners are preserved.)

```
var SEARCH_TERM = 'awesomeness';
var mungeChildNodes = function(elem) {
    // (*) Note that nodes.length is mutable and we expect it to change as we
    // iterate, because we're adding and removing nodes. We need to pay
    // attention to the value of j to avoid an infinite loop.
    for (var j=0; j<elem.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = elem.childNodes[j];

        // If the current node is a text node,
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            // Split it into a bunch of text chunks delimited by the search term.
            var chunks = node.data.split(SEARCH_TERM);
            // Now, for each chunk of text...
            for (var k=0; k<chunks.length; k++) {
                // make it into a DOM node
                var newNode = document.createTextNode(chunks[k]);
                // and add it before the original node.
                elem.insertBefore(newNode, node);
                j = j + 1; // (*)
                // Then, (don't do this next bit for the last chunk)
                if (k<chunks.length - 1) {
                    // create a link containing the search term
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href', '#foo');
                    link.innerHTML = SEARCH_TERM;
                    // and add the link before the original node, too.
                    elem.insertBefore(link, node);
                    j = j + 1; // (*)
                }
            } // Move to the next text chunk.

            // Remove the original node.
            elem.removeChild(node);
            j = j - 1; // (*)

        // Recurse into subnodes, too, unless the node is a link.
        } else if (node.childNodes.length > 0 && node.tagName !== 'A') {
            mungeChildNodes(node);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not very efficient because it will recurse through all text nodes underneath the element it's passed and perform at least one DOM insertion and removal per node. Therefore you shouldn't run `mungeChildNodes(document.body)` on a big document!

You can simplify the solution somewhat by removing the recursive call to `mungeChildNodes`, but then you'll miss any instance of the search term inside a nested tag, like `<em>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need you use regex with [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622606/1339616) for an example that's basically what you're trying to do.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, because setting `innerHTML` on an element destroys (can destroy?) its children, along with any event listeners attached to them.