# preg_replace php need to replace a string not already wrapped in element

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to replace a string with what would be wrapped in a sort of BBcode style element, but only if that string is not already wrapped in the element.

Example:

> The fox runs really fast through Sudan, but also runs really fast through [country]Canada[/country]

Loopping through a list of all the countries I want to replace and wrap in this country brackets I tried this

```
$replace = preg_replace("#(?<!\[country(.)\])". preq_quote($country) ."(?!\[/country\])#", "[country]{$country}[/country]", $replace);
```

Expected output:

> The fox runs really fast through [country]Sudan[country], but also runs really fast through [country]Canada[/country]

But Im actually getting

Actual output:

> The fox runs really fast through [country]Sudan[country], but also runs really fast through [country][country]Canada[/country][/country]

If its already wrapped, I dont want to re-wrap it.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags . Example pattern: `searchtext(?![^\[]*>|[^\]]*\[\/)`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: however, it is a slow way since you must search forward (the lookahead) for each country position in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, you can use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick to skip all that you want in a string:

```
$listOfCountries = array('France', 'Soudan', 'Quatar', 'China', 'Zimbabwe');

$pattern '~\[country][^[]+\[/country](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?i:'
       . implode('|', $listOfCountries) . ')\b~';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '[country]$0[/country]', $text);
```

`(*SKIP)` forbids to retry a substring when the pattern fails later, and `(*FAIL)` forces the regex engine to fail.

Note: if you are sure that the list of countries only contains letters and spaces, you don't need to use preg_quote. However if your list contains abbr like R.D.C. ("République Démocratique du Congo"), it is better to use preg_quote. Be careful, if you have abbr in the list `\b` will no more work, you must replace it with an other kind of boundary (since the dot is not in `\w`), example:`(?=\s|[^\PP.])` *(a white character or a punctuation character that is not a dot)*

Comment: @KyleBrowning: In this case, You can sort and divide your array. For each chunk, you can build strings with first letters in factor, example: `AL(BANIE|GERIA)|BE(LGIQUE|N(IN|GLADESH))...` .(you can build this by hand, but I'm sure it is possible to build a function to do that for you once and for all)