# Matching all "es" in "test <test> test </test> test" that are NOT between angle brackets

Tags: regex

In the string "test <test> test </test> test" i want to match only these occurrences of "es":

"t**es**t <test> t**es**t </test> t**es**t"

Anyone knows how to do this?

**This is not the same as as the possible duplicate** [Regex replace text outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags) where the result would be

"t**es**t <test> test </test> t**es**t", as the inner "es" is not getting matched

Update: forgot to mention that <test> should be replaceable with <any stuff="test">...</any> or <testing some="stuff">...</testing>.

JavaScript regex flavor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex replace text outside html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags)

Comment: @dakab no, not the same. I now added an explanation. (but I'm upvoting the comment, as it is a helpful reference)

Comment: What language and what regex did you try?

Comment: @bobblebubble The "JavaScript (Chrome)" mode in RegexBuddy. I really didn't get to try, I thought about it, tried some stuff with lazy matching, but gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for PCRE you can [skip](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28*SKIP%29-%28*SKIP:NAME%29) the tags

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|es
```

`<` matches literally, followed by [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^>]*` any amount of character, that are not `>` followed by literal `>` and is skipped `|` or `es` is matched in the remaining text.

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lK5fZ9/1). Or use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
es(?![^<]*>)
```

After matching `es` literally `(?!` starts a negative lookahead to check if it's not before a closing `>` with no `<` in between. If there's NOT any amount of [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)`<` followed by literal `>` ahead.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lK5fZ9/2)

Comment: This makes me love regex (went with the lookahead)

Comment: @DanielF Good it works for you! Added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hC6uC8/1)

```
<test>|<\/test>|(es)
```

which matches tags, but only capture the non-tags.

Comment: Could you modify this for any tag, even tags with attributes in them? (Sorry I had to unapprove the answer, noticed to late that it was limited to the test string. will update the question)

Comment: Have you not heard on SO that you should not use regex in the general case but use a proper parser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: This is what regex was made for. I mean, this matching through simple logic. No grammar required for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`/(es)(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/g`** yourself or [view it in the tester](https://regex101.com/r/mN6xE8/1).

It uses a positive look-ahead to ensure that anything other than a closing angle bracket follows, right to the next opening angle bracket or the end of the string.

Note that [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in particular have quite varying support, depending on the flavor you are using. You might get lucky with look-ahead, however.

Comment: If I could, I would also accept this one. I'm accepting "bobble bubble"'s one because it's shorter. But thanks, and congrats.

Comment: While the accepted answer might be the best solution provided, shortness (or verboseness) shouldn’t be the only criterion. Thanks anyway for the consideration.