# Find text between square brackets outside HTML tags

Tags: java, regex

I saw all possible duplicates to my question but they don't resolve my problem.
For example, I have this text:

```
This [is] a [text] in <ignore>square [brackets]</ignore>
```

I need to find only text in square brackets outside `<ignore></ignore>` tags. In this case these words are `is` and `text`.
How to do this (preferably with Java Regex)?

Comment: What do you need to do with those bracketed texts? Please provide expected output and what you have tried. And why regex is chosen if it is a mark up text?

Comment: What should happen if `<ignore>` occurs inside the square brackets?

Comment: @DavidWallace this will not happen

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why do you need to know what I will do with that texts? Expected output, as I wrote, are words "is" and "text". I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags

Comment: Use two regular expressions.  The first one will get rid of everything in the ignore tags; the second one will pick out the square brackets.

Comment: @Igorock I have never tried such thing with regex, but with a programmatic approach will can definitely do that!

Comment: Why? Because solutions will differ if you want to get an array/list of the matches, or replaced string if you need to remove/replace them.

Comment: Did you already consider first removing the entries between the `ignore` tags, e.g. using `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove everything within `<ignore>` tags:

```
   str = str.replaceAll("<ignore>((?!</ignore>).)*</ignore>", "");
```

After, create the following pattern to find everything within brackets:

```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]").matcher(str);
   while (m.find()) {
    str = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(str);
   }
```