# mark text in a string with regular expression but exclude links

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text and I want when a user search for a term, the term becomes highlighted by wrapping the term with mark tag.

javascript to wrap the match term:

```
var sampleText = window.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var _keywordHighlight = function (text, term) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('('+term+')', 'gi');
  text = text.replace(pattern, '<mark>$1</mark>');;
  return text;
};

var newText = _keywordHighlight(sampleText, 'sample');
window.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newText;
```

jsfiddle.net link:

https://jsfiddle.net/homa/j0Lgk6pf/

The problem is, the search term inside the url also wraps by mark tag and it broke the link.

How can I exclude links to be wrapped by mark tag?

Comment: Try `var pattern = new RegExp(term+'(?![^>]*>)', 'gi');` and replace with `'<mark>$&</mark>'`. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead to add an additional constraint that the term is not followed by a > without first having a <. This will effectively exclude matches within <...> markup.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('('+term+')(?![^<]*>)', 'gi');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdk80o0k/

Answer (score 0):

1. You're reinverting the wheel
2. Using `innerHTML` will destroy events
3. Using `innerHTML` will trigger regeneration of the DOM

To make thins easy you should use an existing plugin. There are many jQuery plugins out there, but as you haven't added the `jquery` tag I assume that you're searching a plain JS solution. Then the only plugin is [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

[**Example of your use case**](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/hdyLpy37/)