# Search a string but ignore tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Im a trying to search for occurances of a string but dont want to match them if they are part of an anchor tag.

```
var str = 'hey there. <a href="github.com">github.com/bvaughn</a>';
str.match(/git/gi)
```

The above code matches both the git inside href and the innerHTML of the anchor tag. I want to ignore the first match. Ignore the opening and closing tab but still search the innerHTML.

Can this be done by modifying the regex? I have tried a couple of combinations but Im just not getting it right.

**Update**

Let me explain my actual usecase. I am trying to create search interface similar to the built in search in chrome, where we highlight the text occurrences in a page. For this I use a react component - [react-highlight-words](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-highlight-words/). This works totally fine for normal text but I want to autolink urls in the text before I highlight them.

Having markup in the text and passing that to the above component messes up the markup as it matches character in it too. So I want it to igore the anchor tag's opening and closing tag but consider the rest.

[This is where the relevant matching happens.](https://github.com/bvaughn/highlight-words-core/blob/master/src/utils.js#L77-L85) I was hoping I could somehow tweak the regex to ignore the anchor tag.

Comment: matching html with reg exp is a bad idea

Comment: Why not just assign that string as the `innerHTML` of an element and search the element for the text rather than the string? Yes, it's probably possible with some edge-cases and restrictions, but why take all that time to do something that is otherwise so simple?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040770/how-to-only-select-text-outside-of-a-tag-in-jquery

Comment: `str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"").match(/git/gi)`

Comment: i added an answer that removes the entire `<a href=""></a>`  element, and not just the HTML tags

Comment: I have updated the question with my use case.

Comment: This answer worked for my use case. I couldn't find this earlier with my searches and hence asked again. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40263903/548568

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```js
var str = 'hey there. <a href="github.com">github.com/bvaughn</a>';
str = str.replace(/<.*>(.*)<\/.*>/g, "$1")
console.log(str);
str.match(/git/gi)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I'm annoyed by the question and the answers. This topic has been discussed dozens of times here on SO.

First of, you should *not* use the answer from mike510a. The answer from JuniorNunes7 should only be used in case your content isn't in the DOM already. Here are the reasons:

- `innerHTML` will destroy events!
- `innerHTML` will trigger regeneration of the DOM!

In order to avoid this you'll need to modify text nodes itself. But, instead of reinverting the wheel [here's](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/) a comparison of text highlighter plugins using jQuery. The only one that is using plain JavaScript is [mark.js](https://markjs.io/). Since you're using React, I'd recommend to use this.

Example in your situation:

```js
new Mark(document.querySelector(".context")).mark("git");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.4.0/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="context">
  hey there. <a href="github.com">github.com/bvaughn</a>
</div>
```

**For your interface you may have a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/).**

It also has an option to ignore matches inside specific elements e.g. links.

Comment: By far the worst answer -- you have added an entire library of extra javascript code to do such a simple thing that requires only one or two lines. There's nothing wrong with modifying the DOM - thats what Javascript is basically designed to do anyways.

Good answer tho -- probably a lot less work in the long run..

Comment: I disagree. If you're implementing it right it will need more code. You'll have to iterate over text nodes, find matches, split the next nodes, insert a newly created `<mark>` element. Since he wan'ts to build a search he also needs a method to remove highlights – another method is necessary. In fact you'll quickly realize that this is what mark.js does and there's no reason to reinvert the entire wheel.

Comment: After edit, now you are right -- the use case wasn't actually on the original question -- it would be far more work to implement such a thing correctly most likely