# How to use jquery to highlight the search keyword in search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example, there is following html in search results, and the `aa` is the keyword:

```
<body>
<div>
    <h2><a href="#aa">aabbcc</a></h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2><a href="#bb">aaeeedd</a></h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2><a href="#cc">vvaapp</a></h2>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to highlight the search keyword `aa` in results and don't change other anything :
I try this:

```
var text = $('body').html().replace(new RegExp('aa','gim'),"<span class='highlight'>aa</span>");
$('body').html(text);
```

But all html were replaced, include the href '#aa'.
I think use the `each()` and `text()` maybe ok.
And is there better solution?

Comment: use `.text()` if text only

Comment: @guradio I think it's bad idea to use `.text()` and replace text then apply text output to body !!

Comment: You want to replace the text of `"aa"` with the text `"bb"` through the whole document? In response to what event?

Comment: @David Thomas I want to highlight the search keyword in the search results

Comment: @DavidThomas is @ working?

Comment: Highlight how, exactly? Replacing one string with another string doesn't typically highlight anything.

Comment: @DavidThomas  It just a example, replace with `<span class="highlight">aa</span>` is work

Comment: Please add details like that to your question, where more people can see, more clearly, what you want the code to do. :)

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313088/3894981

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('div a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('aa', 'bb')); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#aa">aabbcc</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#bb">aaeeedd</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#cc">vvaapp</a></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Using replace and `.text()`

```js
$('div a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace(/[aa]+/g, "bb")); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#aa">aabbcc</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#bb">aaeeedd</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#cc">vvaapp</a></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Using regex

Comment: May be using regex will be better. It can handle replace of multiple occurance..

Comment: @Reddy check update

Comment: The html is just a example, maybe more complicate in actual. I want to just select a container div, then the content will be all replaced. Is the `.each()` and `.text()` required?

Comment: yes because if you dont loop through each element you will not change all of them.

Comment: @guradio if the `<a>` contains a `<span>`? `.text()` will clear that.

Comment: no it will get only text value

Comment: the `.text()` can not get the `<span>`, so the `<span>` will be lost after replace, this is not quite what I want.

Comment: no that span will not be affected. you should add more details in your OP there are so many things that you expect that is not included in the OP

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#filter').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var keyword = event.currentTarget.value;
  highlight('a', keyword);
});

function highlight(selector, keyword) {
  $(selector).each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var original = $element.data('originalText');
    if (original == undefined) {
      original = $element.html();
      $element.data('originalText', original);
    }
    $element.html(original.replace(keyword, '<span class="highlight">' + keyword + '</span>'));
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="filter"/>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#aa">aabbcc</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#bb">aaeeedd</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="#cc">vvaapp</a></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your coding! But I can just select a container tag that maybe include many different tag contains the keyword not just `<a>` using RegExp and it don't need `.each()`, look for my code in answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your best off using text.textContent()
Its easier
Remember you can still use Jquery and JS at once

Answer (score -1):

I found a function to solve it! And it is working well!

```
//highlight the search keyword
function highlight($area,keyword) {
    var re = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ")(?=[^<>]*<)","gi");
    var html = $area.html().replace(re, '<span class="searchkeyword">$1</span>');
    $area.html(html);
}

highlight($('body'), 'aa');
```