# Javascript .replace() - Keep HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

This is my js function

```
function con (text_input){
    return text_input
        .replace(/O/g, 0)
        .replace(/I/g, 1)
        .replace(/o/g, 0)
        .replace(/i/g, 1)
        .replace(/t/g, 4)
        .replace(/d/g, 9)
}
```

In this, I need to keep all html elements like `<td>`, `<div>`, etc., But this function replaces html elements also. Ex:
`console.log(con('<td>OIoitd</td>'))` returns `<49>010149</49>` but I need `<td>010149</td>`. How can I do that?

Comment: either just pass in the inner text, instead of the entire dom element, or make your regex a bit smarter to not search within <>

Comment: Unless you’re in some sort of restricted subset of HTML, you’ll need an HTML parser. Doesn’t need to be a tree-based one, though; you can just do replacements in the `text` event with https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2, taking care to escape properly.

Comment: @AndrewP Yes., but I dont know how to do that :( and contets dynamic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags

Comment: Do you look for a server-side or a client-side solution?

Comment: @t.niese yeah.. client side solution I need. This is for some `paste your code here and get results` type function :)

Answer (score 0):

updated my code. hope this one words out, and yea im using jquery:

```
var text_input ='<td>OIoitd</td>';
function con (text_input){
    //getting text to be replaced
    var innerText = $(text_input)[0].innerHTML;
    //getting text to be replaced with
    var newInnerText = $(text_input)[0].innerHTML.replace(/O/g, 0).replace(/I/g, 1).replace(/o/g, 0).replace(/i/g, 1).replace(/t/g, 4).replace(/d/g, 9);
    //replacing text 
    return text_input.replace(innerText,newInnerText);
}
```

Comment: If not `<td>` but some other html elements, then ? and my `text_input` includes html elements

Comment: You should always explain what the answer in you code does. And what libraries you use if you introduce a library that is not mentioned in the question. `$`  is most likely jQuery, but from the question it is not clear if the OP using this script server side or client side. Beside that this would - ignoring that you hard coded it for `td` - only work if `text_input` is always in the form `<tag>text without any html tags</tag>`, because it would strip all html tags in the `text_input`.

Comment: my bad. ill work on not hard coding the parent element.