# Replace and substitution of texts

Tags: regex

```
In an HTML page, replace the text micro with &micro; and don't screw up the code: don't replace inside <the tags> or &entities;
```

I want to replace list from left to right.

```
micro    &micro; 
micro;   &micro;;
micro>   &micro;>
```

My code can match `micro` `micro>` `micro;` `&micro;`

```
(micro)(?![^;&< ]*;[;>])
```

or match `micro` `micro>` only

```
(micro)(?![^;&< ]*;)
```

But I only want to match `micro` `micro>` `micro;` without `&micro;`

It's not simple as I thought.

### Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/195)

Substitution

```
&micro;
```

### Reference

[Regex replace text outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing you can do with your given regex is checking in callback function of replace.

```js
let str = `micro    &micro; 
micro;   &micro;;
micro>   &micro;>`

let op = str.replace(/(&?micro)(?![^;&< ]*;[;>])/g, function(match,g1) {
  if( g1.startsWith('&') ) {
    return `${g1};`
  } else {
    return `&${g1};`
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!&)(micro)` works for the given example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!&)(micro[^A-Za-z0-9])
```

Working Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pxALtw/1/