# match text outside specific html tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-lookarounds

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags), how does one match text outside of a specific HTML tag?

target text: "targetstring"
excluding HTML tag: script

```
<div>
    <h1>targetstring</h1> <= should match
    <span>targetstring</span> <= should match
</div>
<script>
   var blah = 'targetstring'; <= should not match
</script>
targetstring <= should also match
```

EDIT:
Forgive me for the fogginess of a duplicate. No, this is not a duplicate. The inspired-linked question is for matching *any* tags. This question is for matching a *specific* tag.

I have tried using the regex `(?<!<script(?:.|\n)*)targetstring(?!(?:.|\n)*<\/script>)` as a possible solution but no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex replace text outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags)

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `(?<!<script(?:.|\n)*)thisspecificone(?!(?:.|\n)*<\/script>)`. I also updated the answer

Comment: Never use `(?:.|\n)*`. Use `[\w\W]*` or `[^]*`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var blah = 'thespecialone';
var matchedElements = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"),function(element) {
    return element.textContent === blah;
});
console.log(matchedElements);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>thespecialone<h1>
</div>
```

**Note**
I assumed you want exact match

Comment: excuse me for the confusion. the goal here is to use a regex to match the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression with grouping to get all the content from all the tags.

```js
rule = /<(\w+>)(.+)<\/?\1/g;
```